# Sorted div based on data-attribute timestamp into separate divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a for loop that places divs these divs gets sorted by date with the data-timestamp they have.

Now I want to wrap the items into divs this is the code for the sorting:

```
var albumSort = function () {
    //All album thumbnails in items
    var album = $(".photo-album");
    var items = $(".js-album-thumbnail");
    //items in Array
    var arr = $.makeArray($(items));

    console.log(album);
    console.log(items);

    //Sorting the album thumbnails array
    arr.sort(function(a, b) {
        //item a < b so the higher the time the higher the position
        return new Date( $(a).attr('data-timestamp') ) < new Date( $(b).attr('data-timestamp') );
    });

    console.log(arr);

    //Appending the Array items to the album
    $(album).append(arr);
};
albumSort();
```

After this function they will get for looped on the page. Now I would like to wrap the items in th array into divs based on the time so if the timestamp is `2015/01/01 08:10:15` it has to wrap into:

```
<div class="08"></div>
```

The looped item and if timestamp is `2015/01/01 12:10:15` into:

```
<div class="08"></div>
<div class="12"></div>
```

With all the other items with the same time in hours

```
<div class="js-album-thumbnail" data-original="" data-downloadable="" data-timestamp="2015/11/19 16:32:52" data-thumbnail="" data-share=""><img src=""></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that something like that could work :

```
for (var i=0; i<24; i++){
    $(".js-album-thumbnail").each(function(){
        var element = this;
        if ((new Date(element.attr("data-timestamp"))).getHours() == i){
            $("div."+i).append(element)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey where would i put this in the function where i sort the divs or outside?

Comment: You can add it inside your function i think, if it doesnt work try to use the

    $(function(){
         [code here]
     });